# Possible to execute ForEach-Object commands in Parallel

Tags: powershell

I have been attempting to execute parallel commands on data (such as a list of Server Names) that is imported via CSV and called by `ForEach-Object`. I have found that foreach has a parallel method but it appears that `ForEach-Object` does not. I am concerned about good performance as I hit multiple servers to read log data, and have the following options:

```
1) PowerShell Workflow 
2) PowerShell Background Job 
3) Invoke-Command
```

When I tried option 3, it failed as I tried to send arguments via -ArgumentList, but it didn't seem to like the variables I was pushing from the CSV in the form of:

```
$($_.'CSVColumnValue')
```

Is it possible to execute commands in parallel using `ForEach-Object`, and if so, what is the recommended method to achieve this?

Comment: please add your code to your question, otherwise it's difficult to give advice

Comment: You also may want to look at [Invoke-ScriptAsync](https://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/invoke-scritptasync-v2/) which uses RunSpace Pools to quickly run a script against a list of servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as 'ForEach-Object -Parallel' since it is performed in the pipeline. Check [Erik Meijer and Jeffrey Snover at MSDN Channel 9](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Expert-to-Expert-Erik-Meijer-and-Jeffrey-Snover-Inside-PowerShell); those folks are gettin' nitty-gritty on the pipeline of PowerShell. It's a vid from 2008, lasts over an hour, but still... excellent on how the pipeline works.

The 'ForEach -Parallel' is a construct and not a pipeline cmdlet. It is part of the [Workflow](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713711(v=wps.630).aspx) module and introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0.

Compare:

```
$Items = 1..42
ForEach -Parallel ($Item in $Items) {
 $Item
}
```

With:

```
1..42 | ForEach-Object -Process { $_ }
```

Comment: So it's not possible to use any of the other constructs from ForEach-Object such as `-Begin {}` then?

Answer (score 1):

As far as invoke-command goes, you would need to use the 'using' scope to access local variables:

```
$a = 'hi there'
invoke-command comp001 { echo $using:a }
```

Or to pipe something in:

```
1,2,3 | invoke-command comp001 { echo $input }
```

-argumentlist only works if there's a param defined in the scriptblock.  The docs aren't good on this point.

```
$a = 'hi'
invoke-command comp001 { param($a) echo $a } -ArgumentList $a
```

Unless you use args:

```
invoke-command comp001 { echo $args[0] } -ArgumentList $a
```

Powershell 7 preview 3 actually has a multi-thread "foreach-object -parallel":

```
 1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { sleep 10; 'done' }
```